# Accessing local file with Ajax on Windows phone 8

Tags: c#, ajax, browser, windows-phone-8

I have a page Index.html which call a javascript, that make a ajax request looking for a local .html file
This file is imported in my C# project as content and the javascript fire inside a WP8 webbrowser control.

The problem is that the ajax function return an access denied error.
What can i do?

sorry for my broken english

**Resolved by adding isLocal:true in the ajax request**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "page.html",
    dataType: "html",
    async: false, // Otherwise Android 2.2 doesn't show menu
    isLocal: true, // Or Windows Phone will say "Access is denied" to ajax request
    success: function(html) {
       //success code!
    }
});
```

Comment: It's OK to answer your own question.

Comment: Hi Fabio, could you please send the code or sample to how you have achieved this ? I am also having the same issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Manic I added the how our request is structured

Comment: For me isLocal didn't help, still "Access denied" on WP8.1. But I've heard they have changed a lot in the latest jQuery, which might affect AJAX functionality.

Comment: @Martin Hi, I'm moving the app right now to silverlight 8.1 and seen that it doesn't work anymore. Did you resolved the issue on 8.1? Have any pointer?

Comment: @Fabio No, I did not found a reliable solution. But we moved to Cordova now and Cordova has a custom implementation of XHR request object which overrides the default one and allows to load local files. In case you decide to go that rote you can find XHRHelper.cs file in the Cordova source and try to inject it into Web View control in your application.