# WP8 emulator local ajax calls not working

Tags: jquery, windows-phone-8

I'm converting a html5 Phonegap app that is working perfectly fine on android and ios to wp8 app, currently my ajax calls aren't working..strangely remote ajax calls work. heres the working ajax call:

```
function textSearch() {
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST",
        url: baseUrl + "ajax/AppService.aspx/GetByFullSearch",
        data: JSON.stringify({"query":$('#search_location').val()}),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (all) {
            searchResult = all.d;
            showLocationResult();
        }
    }); 
};
```

heres my local ajax call which is not working:

```
$.ajax({url:"./pages/result.html" ,success:function(result){
    $("#maincontents").html(result);
}});
```

I tried this which is the same thing and also doesn't work

```
$.ajax({
         url: "./pages/result.html",
         cache: false
        })
     .done(function( html ) {
     alert("hello?");
        $( "#maincontents" ).append( html );
  });
```

I'm getting an error from ajax as follows:

```
error:function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown ){
    alert(textStatus);
},
```

textStatus returns "error"..... 
The emulator uses ie10, I've looked into resetting ie10 settings, updated the emulator,
tried to add dataType: 'html', cache: false, no luck

Hope someone has an idea this is driving me nuts!

Comment: Could this be related to your question?  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15679045/accessing-local-file-with-ajax-on-windows-phone-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve this, the phonegap file was bombing out:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-3761

Change line 6258 of Cordova.js from:

```
"File", "readResourceAsText", [alias._url]
```

to:

```
"File", "readResourceAsText", [alias._url, "", 0, 0]
```

Beyond this you also want to specify the full path for WP:

$.ajax({url:"**www/pages/result.html**",success:function(result){